# Android ksoap2 https connection issue

Tags: android, https, ksoap2

I'm using ksoap 2 with android and particularly the class HttpsTransportSE to connect to my wsdl. I have a separate project of testing of the WSDL java client and everything works fine. However when I start using my client on the Android framework something very funny happens:

the first time I call a wsdl it works! second time I get an empty request (and it doesn't work) third time works, fourth doesn't... and so on and forth. I tried closing the HttpsTransportSE connection by doing:

```
_httpsTransport.reset();
_httpsTransport.getConnection().disconnect();
```

by that doesn't seem to fix it. It's a very strange problem and I've been stuck for a while! Anybody has any idea? The WSDL is fine because I already use it for my IPhone App and now I'm doing the Android version of it. It's something related with android connectivity and KSOAP since when I do my testings without Android everything works like a charm!

Any idea would help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

See http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=35